# How to geocode places autocomplete input if user doesn't select a place

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-places

I've been trying to incorporate Places Autocomplete from Google maps into an address field, but I'm having trouble geocoding the input.  Autocomplete is works flawlessly, my issue is that if a user where to type out their address, (or zipcode, or whatever), and then tab or click away from the address field without selecting an address from the dropdown there is no place_change event fired and the address will never be geocoded and stored.

Here is the code:

```
var placeSearch,autocomplete;
var latlng = {
  'lat': 'lat',
  'lng': 'lng'
};
function initialize() {

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#userLocation").blur(function(e){
        google.maps.event.clearInstanceListeners(autocomplete);
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': document.getElementById('autocomplete') }, function(results) {
            //  var latlng = results[0].geometry.location;
            window.lat = results[0].geometry.location.k;
            window.lng = results[0].geometry.location.B
            //  console.log(latlng);
            //  console.log(location_type);
            console.log(lat);
            console.log(lng);
        });
    });
});

var options = {
    types: ['geocode']
};
autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(document.getElementById('autocomplete'), options);
google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
   fillInPlaceLatLng();
});
}
function fillInPlaceLatLng() {
  var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
  var lat = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lat();
  var lng = autocomplete.getPlace().geometry.location.lng();
  console.log(place);
  console.log(lat);
  console.log(lng);

  document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
  document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;

  for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
    var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
    if (latlng[att]) {
        var val = place.address_components[j][latlng[att]];
        document.getElementById(att).value = val;
    }
  }
}
function geolocate() {

  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
        var geolocation = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude,position.coords.longitude);
        autocomplete.setBounds(new google.maps.LatLngBounds(geolocation, geolocation));
  });
  } else {
      var autocompleteResult = document.getElementById('autocomplete').value;
      console.log(autocompleteResult);
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix this by accessing the Maps API geocoder prior to running the autocomplete code.

```
jQuery("#autocomplete").blur(function(e){
console.log(e);
console.log(this.value);
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': this.value }, function(results) {
       var lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
       var lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
        document.getElementById('lat').value = lat;
        document.getElementById('lng').value = lng;
    });
});
```

This way if the user selects a location through autocomplete both sets of coordinates will be returned but the coordinates from autocomplete (the correct ones) will be returned last and will be used. If a user tabs or clicks out of the field then only the first set will be returned.

Comment: You shouldn't rely on `.k` or `.b` to get latitude or longitude from a `LatLng` object. Instead of it, use `results[0].geometry.lat()` and `results[0].Geometry.lng()` to get latitude and longitude. Thanks to this, you avoid unexpected problems in (very) near future.

Comment: @AlexB Please elaborate a little on this. My code was working the other day, and now I cannot get it to work whether I use .k / .b or .lat() / .lng()

Comment: Update: The code is working again with `results[0].geometry.lat()` and `results[0].Geometry.lng()`

Comment: This is why you always have to use `.lat()` et `.lng()` on `LatLng` objects, as documented here : https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng